# Where are the static methods in gcc's dump file.c.135r.jump

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction

When I run gcc with the parameter `-fdump-rtl-jump`, I get a dump file with the name `file.c.135r.jump`, where I can read some information about the intermediate representation of the methods in my C or C++ file.

I just recently discovered, that the static methods of a project are missing in this dump file. Do you know, why they are missing in that representation and if there is a possibility to include the static methods in this file, too.

**Update (some additional information):**
The test program, I'm using here, is the [Hybrid OpenMP MPI Benchmark](http://sourceforge.net/projects/homb/).

**Update2:**
I just reproduced the problem with a serial application, so it has nothing to do with parallel sections.

Comment: Can you share a serial minimal sample code that illustrates this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the static methods are inlined and, since they are static, everything is known about their calls, no out-of-line code of them is emitted.  A way to confirm or reject this is to add `-fkeep-inline-functions` gcc option and then they should appear in the dumps.

Comment: I think I found the mistake. Optimizations were switched on... But your tip got me on the right way, so you get the bounty. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

They are not missing, and this has nothing to do with class methods. I believe that you are just not calling them.

Comment: Oh, you are right. That could be possible. I haven't thought of that. I will check that, later.

Comment: Hm, actually, they are called, but in a parallel OpenMp Section.